# How do I convert a dataset of numeric values into binary values in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset (let's call it `d.f`) with a range of values 0 - 10000. I want values 3000 > to = 0 and values 3000 =< to equal 1. How do I convert the values in `d.f` to 0 and 1?

Thanks in advance for any replies!

Comment: `ifelse(d.f > 3000, 0, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ifelse`. For example,

```
ifelse(d.f> 3000,0,1)
```